# Check collision between 2 shapes

Tags: actionscript-3, collision, shapes, hittest

I'm writing a little game in as3, and I need to check collision between 2 boats.
I don't need the pixel perfect collision, but bounds collision is not enough too.
The boat look more or less like this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/197yqvzf2jaugtm/boats.JPG

I was thinking about create one square on the back of the boat and a triangle on the front, than for each boat, check if the square collide with the other boat square or triangle, and the same for the triangle.

I just don't know how to do that, I don't know if it's possible with the Shape.hitTest, or if it's the best way to do that.

What can I do?

Comment: I don't have a direct answer to this but I've played a bit with some really basic top down shooter game development (using no third-party libraries just AS3 and I may have used Grant Skinner's class here http://www.freeactionscript.com/2009/05/pixel-perfect-collision-detection/) and doing the hit detection with PNGs seemed to perform just fine.  Even adding tons of enemies on screen and lots of missles it didn't lag much considering no framework/optimization.

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I'm using starling as a framework to build my game. This class uses DiplayObjectContainer from flash, and I use displayObjectContainer from starling.. Already tried to change the import, but doesn't work too

Comment: Using Starling as you say you end up using a different set of objects that don't inherit from the flash API, they are generally lighter weight I believe.  Check out the discussion here: http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/collision-detection  Basic conclusion is you can use a couple of rectangles to approximate, since the textures are on the GPU the CPU isn't really able to get at the information for where each pixel is (without slowing the GPU thereby negating the point of using GPU acceleration).

Comment: That's why I was wondering if I can't create a shape, in the boat format (using more or less 5 points) and use the Shape.hitTest for each point of the other boat, if one of them return true, there is collision, but I don't know how hitTest from Shapes works. Is that a good solution? and will it work?

Comment: Yup I understand your drift now but I haven't tried it myself, will do a bit of searching in the docs and see if I can point anything out.  I think what you're trying to do won't work out well, you'd be better off dropping starling if you're going to be mirroring things using the Flash display objects in order to compute the hitTest, I don't think it will work for invisible display objects.  If you stick in starling I think your best bet is manually doing the hit detection http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/Polygon_Collision the point in polygon solution seems like it would work.

Comment: I have to stay with starling.
This look like a good solutions, but what about rotations? :/

Comment: I think you would need to define the polygon as an array of points, and build your own shape object that will tell you what the points are after rotation so you can separate the concerns of figuring out the polygon points and doing the collision detection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10533403/how-to-rotate-a-polygon-around-a-point-with-java  Given the complexity of the task I would strongly consider just using multiple rectangles and the intersect method instead, using 4 or so rectangles you can closely approximate the pointed part of a boat (rotation may still complicate things).

Comment: This tutorial might be helpful: http://www.sevenson.com.au/actionscript/sat/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var isTouched:Boolean = item1.bounds.intersects(item2.bounds);
```

when both touches, it will return true;